# Maven shade IllegalStateException - Required class information is missing

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-shade-plugin

I just finished building an application using JavaFX and Hibernate, which builds and run perfectly on IntelliJ, so I choose to generate a "fat-jar" using maven shade plugin, since I make use of some libraries with automatic module names, so I cannot use jlink.

Jar is created fine, it loads the initial screen correctly, however when it tries to make connection to my database, specifically this line is the problematic (JPAUtil.java:19);

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit, properties);
```

I get the following exceptions;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required class information is missing
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.rebuildNestedType(Indexer.java:926)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.resolveTypePath(Indexer.java:786)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.resolveTypeAnnotation(Indexer.java:705)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.resolveTypeAnnotations(Indexer.java:613)
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassDescriptor(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at com.it.util.JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtil.java:19)
    at com.it.controller.HomeController.initializeSettings(HomeController.java:1571)
    at com.it.controller.HomeController.initialize(HomeController.java:1407)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at com.it.Home.start(Home.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I know the syntax is correct as I mentioned before it runs correctly on IDE, so I suspect it is something missing on the jar file generated by shade, however I've spend almost 3 days on this already and I simply cannot find a reason. Information shown on the stacktrace doesn't help much, at least I don't see anything - I did even looked to all classes mentioned on the stacktrace and they all seem to be on the generated Jar.
Hoping anyone here had something similar or is maybe more familiar than me on the maven shade process. Any help or point to look at would be appreciated.

Additional files which would help to identify the problem is as follow;

persistence.xml - other properties are loaded from a XML file on the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    
    <persistence-unit name="Project-Postgre">
        <description>Hibernate JPA Configuration</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value = "false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.it</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>14</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <name>Project</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.jensd/fontawesomefx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.it.HomeFX</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                            <outputFile>target\shade\${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.it.HomeFX</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JPAUtil

```
public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnit, String connectionURL, String user, String password) {
        if (factory == null) {
            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", connectionURL);
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", user);
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit, properties);
        }
        return factory;
}
```

Comment: What about the `persistence.xml` file? are you sure you're having all the information in there? pay attention, that according to your logs, your @Controller can't work, and that's because of `EntityManagerFactory` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sure all is there, as I mentioned before the program works correctly on IntelliJ. In any case, I added my JPAUtil class to the original post as well, so you can see everything additional from the persistence.xml which is being loaded for the emf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to overcome this issue by switching from Hibernate to OpenJPA.
Hibernate did not provide enough information to debug the problem and when switching to OpenJPA I just had to add this to my pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
     <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Shade created the JAR with all required libraries and connection to database was successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error using:
spring.version:5.2.7.RELEASE
spring.boot.version:2.3.1.RELEASE
postgresql-version:42.2.16

It happens with all versions of postgres from 42.2.15. Version 42.2.14 (or earlier)     works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried to downgrade PostgreSQL JDBC driver version to 42.0.0. Exception gone and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by invalid bytecode produced by `javac` 1.8 (e.g. AdoptOpenJDK 1.8u222 is known to be affected).

Here's the issue (with reproducer): https://github.com/wildfly/jandex/issues/92

The fix is to update to `org.jboss:jandex:2.2.3.Final` which includes the workaround (and a couple of other fixes for type annotations), or use Java 11 compiler (== `javac` 11).

---

Just in case, `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.15` triggers the issue since it uses [the Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) for [nullness verification](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/1814), and it includes multiple `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` annotations to make the verifications pass.

The upcoming `org.postgresql:42.2.18` and `org.postgresql:42.3.0` will have [the relevant workarounds](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/2010), so it would work with old `jandex` versions as well.

---

If you are reading here, I would recommend adding [forbidden-apis](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis) and [jandex](https://github.com/wildfly/jandex) bytecode parsers (e.g. `de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis` and `com.github.vlsi.jandex` Gradle plugins) to your build pipeline to capture invalid bytecode early (which might otherwise come unnoticed), especially if you still use `javac` 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, fixed in PostgreSQL JDBC Driver version 42.2.19, see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html#version_42.2.19.

Update your version to 42.2.19 and it should solve the problem.